# is possible to change a loccal user account to a child account?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, parental-controls

I have a family PC with windows 10 pro

A child uses it. Formerly I had windows 7, and the child account had a time limitation which restricted the time at with the child could use the computer

On windows 10 pro, I want to do the same, but Microsoft help only says how to use a microsoft account as child account.

I need to know if I can turn a local account (non microsoft account) to a child account, to restrict the time at wich the PC can be used.

If possible, how do I do it?

If not possible, at least I need to know that is not possible.